# Give argument to PHP function by Ajax (or something else)

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have 4 buttons in HTML Bootstrap and one function in PHP (function with an argument). What I need:

If user clicks the button, it send special argument to function in PHP. I don't know is it wrong or not, but I think this is possible with Ajax...

My code HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn1">b1</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn2">b2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn3">b3</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn4">b4</button>
```

My PHP function:

```
function get_request_to_table($status) {
    include 'db.php';

    if($status == "ARGUMENT1") {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE user='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }

    if($status == "ARGUMENT2") {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE user='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."' ORDER BY id DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);   
    }
```

And I really don't want to make it by HTML form...

Comment: what you have tried??

Comment: where is the ajax code and what variables are the buttons supposed to be passing to PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call

```
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="sendStatus('success')" id="btn1">b1</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="sendStatus('primary')" id="btn2">b2</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="sendStatus('warning')" id="btn3">b3</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="sendStatus('danger')" id="btn4">b4</button>
```

With JQuery you can use the ajax function

```
function sendStatus(status) {
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "yourphpfile.php",
  data: { status: status }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert("Data Saved:" + msg );
  });
}
```

Now you can use $_POST["status"] in your php file.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I need!

Answer (score 2):

First set data attributes on each button. for example

```
<button data-myAttr="ARGUMENT1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn1">b1</button>
```

Next get data-myAttr by `Arg1 = $("#btn1").attr('data-myAttr');` in your script and pass this to your php function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PHP_PATH",
    data: {status: Arg1 },
    success: function () {} });
```

and get it by $_POST['status'] in your php function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a little confusing. You know that `php` will be executed **before** `JavaScript`, right? Are you planning to pre-run all `sql` select statements?

If you are using `Ajax` anyway, you might as well create `php` pages that generate raw `html` fragments and use `Ajax` to get the results.

*datagenerator.php*

```
<?php
$query ="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE user='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."' ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = conn($query);
    if (($result)||(mysql_errno == 0))
    {
      echo "<table width='100%'><tr>";
      if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
      {
              //loop thru the field names to print the correct headers
              $i = 0;
              while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
              {
           echo "<th>". mysql_field_name($result, $i) . "</th>";
           $i++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";

        //display the data
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach ($rows as $data)
          {
            echo "<td align='center'>". $data . "</td>";
          }
        }
      }else{
        echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i+1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    }else{
      echo "Error in running query :". mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.post( "datagenerator.php", { status: "ARGUMENT1" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('#yourContainer').html(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you @Ted , but it's only sample, not my real code. I just want to some kind of other solution.